# TikZ-Feynman two loop box diagram bulged

Tags: tikz-feynman

The following code for a two-loop box diagram produces a bulged rectangle, but I would like the rectangle formed from the two smaller boxes to have straight edges (so that a to b and b to c are at the same angle). How do I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\diagram[horizontal=a to c]{
    i1 -- a -- b -- c -- i3,
    i2 -- d -- e -- f -- i4,
    a -- d,
    b -- e,
    c -- f,
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bulged two-loop box]